# Mongo write taking too long with Pyspark (sharded cluster)

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, nosql

I'm trying to read parquet files and dump it onto mongodb collection (sharded).
When i do it without sharding, the write throughput is really good. But after sharding it has gone down drastically.

A single task is taking 30 mins plus, which is only processing 16 mb data

[image]

I'm using below Spark config

> 

```
(
     SparkConf()
    .setMaster("yarn")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "30g")
    .set("spark.executor.instances", "10")
    .set("spark.executor.cores", "5")
    .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "2000")
    .set("spark.network.timeout", "800")
    .set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "1200")
    .set("spark.default.parallelism", "2000") 
    .set('spark.jars', './mongo*.jar')
    .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", mongo_uri)
    .set("spark.mongodb.input.database", db)
    .set("spark.mongodb.input.collection", db_collection)
    .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", mongo_uri)
    .set("spark.mongodb.output.database", db)
    .set("spark.mongodb.output.collection", db_collection)
    .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.partitionKey", shard_key)
    .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitioner", "MongoShardedPartitioner")
    .set("spark.mongodb.input.partitionerOptions.shardkey", shard_key) 
)
```

I'm looking to dump 20 Billion plus records, 8 hours up and it's only inserted around 800 million documents.

The documents are same size, each document is of 250 KB

No additional indexes are being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else gets into this. for some reason, sparksession level mongo configurations are not used while writing to mongo.

To overcome this, explicitly give mongo configuration in your writing step

```
mongo_conf = {
    'uri': mongo_uri,
    'database': db,
    'maxBatchSize': 100000,
    'forceInsert': True,
    'ordered': False,
    'shardKey': {'your_key': 'hashed'},
    'collection': "test2",
}

(
        df
        .write
        .options(**mongo_conf)
        .format(mongo_format)
        .mode("append").save()
)
```